# Sockets in C++ under ubuntu does not receive data

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm writing small test program. Where I need to send-receive data, using sockets, between several PC's on the local network. I found several examples how to work with the sockets, and, based on them, wrote class ConnectionManager. You can find it in attachments. The problem is that I see that data has been sent, but the other PC is not able to read it. Connections are accepted, at least i see my log in terminal "accept a connection from 192.168.1.30:43778". You can find it in cpp file to. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Most code was taken from this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/
The rest is my experiments.

Header File

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <optional>
#include <netinet/in.h>

namespace ConnectionManager
{

using Data = std::optional<std::string>;
// TODO: add handling of errcode and convert it to ErrorCode enum, add new antries
enum class ErrorCode
{
    SUCCESS,
    FAILED,
};

class Server
{
public:
    Server(size_t port);

    bool openServer();
    Data readData();
    ErrorCode sendData(const std::string& data);
    void closeConnection();
    void closeServer();

private:
    int handle;
    size_t port;
    int sockId;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
};

class Client
{
public:
    Client(size_t port);

    ErrorCode connectToServer(const std::string& remoteIp);
    ErrorCode sendData(const std::string& data);
    Data readData();
    void closeConnection();
private:
    int handle;
    size_t port;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
};
}
```

CPP file

```
#include "ConnectionManager.h"

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>


#include "Log.h"

#define BUF_LEN 1024
namespace ConnectionManager
{

Server::Server(size_t portIn) : handle(0), port(portIn)
{
};

bool Server::openServer()
{
    int opt = 1;
    if ((handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        LOG("Socket creation failed, handle result " << handle);
        return false;
    }
    if (setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        LOG("setsockopt failed: " << strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    long socketFlags = 0;
    if((socketFlags = fcntl(handle, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0){
        LOG("Socket receive configuration error: " << strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
    socketFlags |= O_NONBLOCK | FASYNC;
    if (fcntl(handle, F_SETFL, FASYNC) < 0)
    {
        LOG("Socket set configuration error: " << strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
 
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(handle, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
        LOG("bind failed");
        return false;
    }
    if (listen(handle, 256) < 0) {
        LOG("listen: " << strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

Data Server::readData()
{
    char buffer[BUF_LEN] = "";
    int res = 0;
    int len = BUF_LEN;

    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(address);
    //if ((sockId = accept4(handle, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&address), &addrlen, SOCK_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
    if ((sockId = accept(handle, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&address), &addrlen)) < 0) {
        LOG("accept failed: " << strerror(errno));
        return Data();
    }
    
    //debug
    sockaddr_in peer;
    socklen_t alen = sizeof(peer);
    getpeername(sockId, (sockaddr *) &peer, &alen);
    printf("accept a connection from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr), ntohs(peer.sin_port));

    res = read(sockId, buffer, len);
    //debug
    printf("Server::readData: %s", buffer);
    auto errText = strerror(errno);
    LOG(errText);
    if (res < 0 )
    {
        LOG("Failed to read data from socket: " << res << " - " << strerror(errno));
        return Data();
    }

    return Data(buffer);
}

ErrorCode Server::sendData(const std::string& data)
{
    std::vector<std::string> dataCollection;
    bool finished = false;
    ErrorCode ret = ErrorCode::FAILED;
    std::string localData = data;

    while (!finished)
    {
        dataCollection.push_back(localData.substr(0, BUF_LEN));
        localData.erase(0, BUF_LEN);
        auto res = send(sockId, localData.c_str(), localData.length(), 0);

        if (res == 0 && localData.empty())   
        {
            finished = true;
            ret = ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
        }
        if (localData.empty())
        {
            break;
        }  
    }
    //send(sockId, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0);
    return ret;
}

void Server::closeConnection()
{
    close(sockId);
}

void Server::closeServer()
{
    close(handle);
}

Client::Client(size_t portIn) : handle(0), port(portIn)
{
};

ErrorCode Client::connectToServer(const std::string& remoteIp)
{
    struct timeval tv={1,0};

    if ((handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    {
        LOG("Socket creation error: " << strerror(errno));
        return ErrorCode::FAILED;
    }
 
    setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO | SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &tv, sizeof(tv));

    long socketFlags = 0;
    if((socketFlags = fcntl(handle, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0){
        LOG("Socket receive configuration error: " << strerror(errno));
        return ErrorCode::FAILED;
    }
    socketFlags |= O_NONBLOCK | FASYNC;
    if (fcntl(handle, F_SETFL, FASYNC) < 0)
    {
        LOG("Socket set configuration error: " << strerror(errno));
        return ErrorCode::FAILED;
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
 
    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary
    // form
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, remoteIp.c_str(), &address.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        LOG("Invalid address/ Address not supported: " << strerror(errno));
        return ErrorCode::FAILED;
    }
 
    int status;
    if ((status = connect(handle, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address))) < 0) {
        LOG("Connection Failed: " << strerror(errno));
        return ErrorCode::FAILED;
    }
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode Client::sendData(const std::string& data)
{
    std::vector<std::string> dataCollection;
    bool finished = false;
    ErrorCode ret = ErrorCode::FAILED;
    std::string localData = data;
    //struct timeval tv={3,0};

    //setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO | SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &tv, sizeof(tv));
    while (!finished)
    {
        dataCollection.push_back(localData.substr(0, BUF_LEN));
        localData.erase(0, BUF_LEN);
        auto res = send(handle, localData.c_str(), localData.length(), 0);

        if (res == 0 && localData.empty())   
        {
            finished = true;
            ret = ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
        }
        if (localData.empty())
        {
            break;
        }  
    }
    return ret;
}

Data Client::readData()
{
    char buffer[BUF_LEN] = "";
    int len = BUF_LEN;
    struct timeval tv={3,0};

    setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO | SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &tv, sizeof(tv));
    if (read(handle, buffer, len) < 0 )
    {
    //debug
        printf("Server::readData: %s", buffer);

        LOG("Failed to read data from socket: " << strerror(errno));
        return Data();
    }
    //debug
    printf("Server::readData: %s\n", buffer);

    return Data(buffer);
}

void Client::closeConnection()
{
    close(handle);
}
}
```

Comment: [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: If you use Wireshark or tcpdump, do you see the data being received on the other PC?

Comment: Add a *lot* of logging. Check for errors. And please note that the GfG site have very bad reputation among experienced programmers around here, since it tends to show bad code, bad habits, and too often even invalid code.

Comment: @Barmar Wireshark is not for ubuntu. Will check tcpdump.

Comment: Also please note that the `read` call does not add a string null-terminator. If it's a string then convert the buffer into a `std::string`. And the value of `errno` is *indeterminate* if a function doesn't fail (and is not explicitly documented to set it anyway). And if a function fails, you need to get the value of `errno` *immediately*, any other call would again make its value indeterminate.

Comment: And Wireshark can be installed using the Ubuntu package system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Logging will not help. On debug it just gets stuck on read data, waiting for the incoming data. If socket set to nonblocking, it continues with no errors, but buffer is empty. Most likely I'm missing some settings. The question is, which one?

Comment: If one program gets stuck in a `read` call, the problem is likely on the other end, which doesn't send any data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please check attached code. I'm already doing all conversions.

Comment: Not in `printf("Server::readData: %s", buffer);`. And you don't pass the received length to the `Data` constructor, so it can't create a `std::string` (or other container) using that data either.

Comment: Does the client send data to the server? Also try adding a \n at the end of printing on the server, because some systems don't actually print until the \n is printed.

Comment: Note: `read()` and `write()` don't guarantee to get/put all the data. You need to check the amount on each and keep sending until it has all been retrieved/sent.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are removing data from `localData` before sending it, look at

```cpp
        dataCollection.push_back(localData.substr(0, BUF_LEN));
        localData.erase(0, BUF_LEN);
        auto res = send(sockId, localData.c_str(), localData.length(), 0);
```

Line `localData.erase(0, BUF_LEN);` should be after `send(`

This error is in two places, in client & server

Comment: Thanks. Looks like problem is that I'm using invalid variable in send. The idea was to use separate variable for this. But looks like, I forgot about it :D I have done necessary changes, now it works as expected. Big thanks.